# Pause/Resume download with AFNetworking 3.0 and NSURLSessionDownloadTask Objective-C, OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, afnetworking

I have trouble with creating Pause/Resume download methods in my Objective-C osx app, I have tried some of the answers I found here but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code: `-(void)pauseDownload:(id)sender {
    if(!downloadTask) return;

```
[downloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData:^(NSData * _Nullable resumeData) {

    if (!resumeData) return;
    [self setDownloadResumeData:resumeData];
    [self setDownloadTask:nil];

}];
NSString *datastring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadResumeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
isDownloading = NO;
NSLog(@"data %@", datastring);}`
```

Continue method:

```
-(void)continueDownload:(id)sender {
if (!self.downloadResumeData) {
    return;
}
self.downloadTask = [manager.session downloadTaskWithResumeData:self.downloadResumeData];
[self.downloadTask resume];
[self setDownloadResumeData:nil];}
```

And download request with download task:

```
-(void)downloadRequest:(NSString *)url toDirectory:(NSString *)directoryName atIndex:(NSInteger) rowIndex {

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSString *downloadDirectoryPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"downloadPath"];
NSURL *downloadURL;
if (directoryName != nil || ![directoryName isEqualToString:@""]) {
    downloadURL = [self createDownloadDirectoryIn:downloadDirectoryPath withName:directoryName];
} else {
    downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"downloadFolderPath"]];
}
downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    NSLog(@"%@", downloadProgress);

    //        [self downloadStartedWithDownloadId:downloadID andDeviceId:userDeviceID];

    isDownloading = YES;
    NSNumber *downloadPercentage = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:downloadProgress.fractionCompleted *100];
    progressArray[rowIndex] = downloadPercentage;
    [self updateProgressBars];

} destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    return [downloadURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

    [[files objectAtIndex:self.tableOfContents.selectedRow] setIsFinishedDownloading:YES];
    //        [self downloadFinishedWithDownloadID:downloadID andDeviceID:userDeviceID];
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}] ;
[downloadTask resume];}
```

Appreciate any help.